# Find Integers with Most Divisors

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns the integer with most divisors when provided with a list.

```
def number_of_divisors(k):
    count = 0
    for number in range(1, k+1):
        if k % number == 0:
            count += 1
    return count

def max_divisors(list_i):
    return(max(list_i, key = number_of_divisors))
```

This function works perfectly fine. But if provided with a list like [8,12,18,6], 12 and 18 are tied for maximum number of divisors. It only returns the first item with maximum number of divisors i.e. 12.  I want it to return 18 as well. How to achieve this?

Comment: This question is properly asked, provided the code the OP wrote but asks for help in order to solve something he has no idea how. This does not deserve to be closed as it respects SO rules.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in general a `number_of_divisors` function can be made much faster than `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to collect all the results, and you can use a dictionary to map the number of divisors to the numbers and just return that list of numbers, e.g.:

```
def max_divisors(list_i):
    d = {}
    for n in list_i:
        d.setdefault(number_of_divisors(n), []).append(n)

    return d[max(d)]

>>> max_divisors([8,12,18,6])
[12, 18]
```

Comment: Elegant, but I'd use collections.defaultdict(list) for d

Comment: Indeed, `defaultdict` would work just as well and make the code a little cleaner with the additional `import`.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your `max_divisors` function like this:

```
def max_divisors(items):
    div_list = list(map(number_of_divisors, items))
    most = max(div_list)
    return [items[i] for i, div in enumerate(div_list) if div == most]
```

The first line generates a list of divisors corresponding to your items, so that `div_list[i]` is equal to the number of divisors of the number at `items[i]`. The second line finds the maximum number of divisors, and the third line marches through your divisors list and adds the corresponding number to the return list only if it has the maximum number of divisors.

The third line contains an example of a Python list comprehension; since you're a beginner you may not have seen one of these before. Its general form is

```
[item for item in sequence if cond]
```

an expression which is equivalent to `filtered` in the more verbose code below

```
filtered = []
for item in sequence:
    if cond:
        filtered.append(item)
```

Note that both the `item` and `cond` field in the list comprehension can be any Python expression.

Comment: You could also use `zip()` instead of `enumerate` - `[n for n, div in zip(list, div_list) if div == most]`